# sorting algorithm issue

Tags: sorting, webserver

I need help with my server application problems. Thing is:
I need to count 'top urls' in my web server within a eg one minute. How to acquire it?
by 'top urls' i mean top 10 or something

Suppose in one minute i got:

```
1 request with url 'http://localhost/10.jpg',
2 requests with url 'http://localhost/1.jpg', and 'http://localhots/12.jpg'
4 request with url 'http://localhost/2.jpg' and 'http://localhost/3.jpg'
and 10 requestes for 'http://localhost/13.jpg'
```

Should I add all requestes to table, and then after given time, sort them, or maybe is antoher, simpler way to sort them ?

Thx for all help

Comment: you are writing a web server? or ... ? what about platform? Why not use any of the existing analytics tools? how are your requests stored?

Comment: Its my own application, written in lua in linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping a temporary hit counter for each page, you don't really need to sort.  When you want to start tracking, reset all the temporary counters to 0, and initialize a top ten list of pages.   Every a time page is fetched, increment it's count, then check the value against the top ten list.  If the count is greater than the next higher count on the list, move it up a rank.